# Change ViewModel Property value using plugin in nopCommerce

Tags: plugins, properties, onchange, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I am working on nopCommerce v3.90. I have a requirement to a plugin which would update the original Price of the Product by some percentage ratio based on the settings performed within plugin settings section, without altering the existing nopCommerce model structure.

Hence, each time the product's price is displayed, one should be able to see the new updated price (based on the action performed in a plugin) instead of the price from the database.

Can anyone help me with this?

*Existing Model class in nopCommerce*

```
public partial class ProductPriceModel : BaseNopModel
{
    //block of statements

    public string Price { get; set; } //the property whose value need to be changed from plugin

    //block of statements
}
```

Comment: Override and customize PrepareProductPriceModel() method in  IProductModelFactory class.

Comment: Firstly thanks Raphael for the response. I am still not getting clear on your solution. Just to update the price, why I need to override the complete PrepareProductPriceModel() method. Although the price is calculated based on GetProductPrice() method of TaxService class.

Secondly, Even though if I create, override and define the PrepareProductPriceModel(), how will it get triggered automatically, on the call to default action methods being used for displaying products or product price. Eg: - ProductDetails Action of ProductController.

Comment: Did you solve it? Consider my long explanation below

Answer (score 2):

In **3.9** the options I know are

- Override `PrepareProductPriceModel` method in `IProductModelFactory` class and provide your custom implementation using dependency override
- Implement an `ActionFilter` to customize the `ProductPriceModel` before it gets used in the view.

In **4.0** this is very easy. You only have to subscribe to `ModelPreparedEvent` and then customize the `ProductPriceModel`.

---

**Override** `IProductModelFactory`

```
public class CustomProductModelFactory : ProductModelFactory
{    
    // ctor ....

    protected override ProductDetailsModel.ProductPriceModel PrepareProductPriceModel(Product product)
    {
        // your own logic to prepare price model
    }    
}
```

In your plugin dependency registrar

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomProductModelFactory>()
       .As<IProductModelFactory>()
       .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

---

**Implement** `ActionFilter`

```
public class PriceInterceptor : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));    
        if (filterContext.HttpContext?.Request == null) return;

        if (filterContext.Controller is Controller controller)
        {
            if (controller.ViewData.Model is ProductDetailsModel model)
            {
                // your own logic to prepare price model
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to dynamically provide your ActionFilter

```
public class PriceInterceptorFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return new[] { new Filter(new PriceInterceptor(), FilterScope.Action, null) };
    }
}
```

In your plugin dependency registrar

```
builder.RegisterType<PriceInterceptorFilterProvider>()
       .As<IFilterProvider>();
```

---

**Subscribe to** `ModelPreparedEvent<ProductDetailsModel>` (nopCommerce 4.0)

```
public class PriceInterceptor : IConsumer<ModelPreparedEvent<ProductDetailsModel>>
{
    public void HandleEvent(ModelPreparedEvent<ProductDetailsModel> eventMessage)
    {
        // your own logic to prepare price model
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution.